# Не получается обновить UI из другого потока

Tags: c#, wpf

Вызываю все через диспетчер, считывание работает нормально, а вот присваивание вызывает исключение `Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток` (место пометил комментарием)

```
private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        autosearch = !autosearch;
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Auto_Search));
        t.Start();
    }

private void Auto_Search()
    {
        bool chk = false;
        (int, bool) png = (0, false);
        CheckBox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { chk = (bool)CheckBox1.IsChecked; }));
        Ping.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { png.Item2 = int.TryParse(Ping.Text, out png.Item1); }));
        Paragraph par = Generate();
        main_String.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { main_String.Document = new FlowDocument(par); }));//тут исключение
        string st = "";
        main_String.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { st = new TextRange(main_String.Document.ContentStart, main_String.Document.ContentEnd).Text; }));
        Random rand = new Random();
        int pos1 = rand.Next(st.Length);
        int pos2 = rand.Next(st.Length);
        if (pos1 > pos2)
        {
            int temp = pos1;
            pos1 = pos2;
            pos2 = temp;
        }
        if (chk && png.Item2)
        {
            while (autosearch)
            {
                substring.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { substring.Text = st.Substring(pos1, pos2 - pos1); }));
                (int, int) indexs = Search(out long time);
                if (indexs != (0, 0))
                {
                    string s1 = hash.main_string.Substring(indexs.Item1, indexs.Item2 - indexs.Item1);
                    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
                    p.Inlines.Add(new Run(hash.main_string.Substring(0, indexs.Item1)));
                    p.Inlines.Add(new Run(s1) { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
                    p.Inlines.Add(new Run(hash.main_string.Substring(indexs.Item2)));
                    main_String.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { main_String.Document = new FlowDocument(par); }));
                    Comment_String.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
                    { 
                        Comment_String.Text = $"Подстрока была найдена.\nВремя поиска составило: {time} миллисекунд";
                        Comment_String.Text += $"\nИндекс начала подстроки {indexs.Item1}, индекс конца {indexs.Item2}, длинна строки {indexs.Item2 - indexs.Item1}"; 
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    Comment_String.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { Comment_String.Text = $"Данной подстроки нет в основной строке\nВремя поиска составило: {time} миллисекунд"; }));
                }
                if (png.Item2)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(png.Item1 * 1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А какое именно исключение? `Paragraph` - это контрол? Если да, то его тоже надо наверное создавать в UI потоке.

Comment: Исключение "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток"

Comment: Ну значит то что я выше написал - верное предположение. Контролы должны создаваться в UI потоке, то есть надо исправлять метод `Generate`, который вы не показали. Добавил текст исключения в вопрос.

Comment: А вообще то что вы творите сейчас с WPF, так никто не делает. Опытные разработчики используют привязки данных и асинхронное программирование, а не запуск потока на низком уровне. Вероятно ваш код можно упростить раз в 5, но точно сказать сложно, так как вообще не понятно, что он делает.